# ObjectDataSource stored procedure parameter is from a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, datasource

I'm trying to set an ObjectDataSource up with a GridView in an asp.net web-forms application.  The select command that I plan on using for the ObjectDataSource returns a DataTable by querying the database with a stored procedure, like so:

```cs
public DataTable GetProductsById(string ids = null)
        {

            DataTable productDataTable = new DataTable();

            // Stored procedure (sqldb server) is executed here
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetProductByIdsRML_CLR", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter myParam = new SqlParameter("@ids", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            myParam.Value = (ids);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(myParam);
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

            dataAdapter.Fill(productDataTable);

            return productDataTable;
        }
```

The method takes as an argument a string which is a comma delimited list of Product IDs, this parameter is passed to the stored procedure which then executes the query.  I'm having trouble setting this up correctly, though, because this input `ids` is passed to this method via another method in the code.  Here lies the problem, because when trying to set up the ObjectDataSource, it asks where the parameter for the stored procedure should come from, but "another method" isn't an option.  Here's what I'm talking about:
[image: Choosing parameters for objectdatasource]

None of those options seem to encapsulate "another method in this project".  If anyone knows what to do in this situation, that would be great.  Also, if it's not a good idea to return a DataTable from the stored procedure, that's fine too I can change that fairly easily, but the question still stands.  Thank you!  I feel like there is a very simple solution to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this sorted out thanks to this tutorial on msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581787.aspx

Towards the end of the article it shows how to implement what I want to do in code.  You select "None" from that dropdown and put the parameter in the code behind in the `Selecting` event for the ObjectDataSource, mine looks like this:

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender,
                                           ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.InputParameters["ids"] = SearchResults.idList;
        }
```

Where `idList` is that comma-delimited list of strings that I needed to pass to the stored procedure.  The GridView + ObjectDataSource pretty much takes care of the rest, as long as that idList field is defined each time.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `Session` and then consume the `OnLoadComplete` method of the `Page` and set the `Session` variable in there.

```
protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I thought about doing something like this (storing it in the `Session`), but I thought it might not be the best idea because this argument is going to be a string several thousand characters long, session doesn't seem like the best place for something like that...

Comment: @akowalz, you could use a `Cookie` if you'd like, but I wouldn't say that several thousand bytes of data that can easily be cleaned up is probably a concern.